# gtk+ save file while preserving file permissions in linux

Tags: c, gtk, glib, gtk2

I'm writing a text editor in gtk+ 2.0 & gtksourceview 2.0.  Currently I'm using `gtk_text_buffer_get_text` and `g_file_set_contents` to save the textbuffer to a file.  I see in the docs for `g_file_set_contents` that it says:

> Also since the file is recreated, existing permissions, access control lists, metadata etc. may be lost.

I looked around devhelp and Google and can't find an alternative way to save the textbuffer to a file while preserving file permissions.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Thanks.

Comment: Open the file in a mode that 'truncates' (empties) it, then write out the text buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ptomato suggested using a method that truncates the file, then writing out the text buffer worked as desired.  Here is a snippet of code which worked for me:

```
gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(tbuffer,&end_iter);
gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(tbuffer,&start_iter);
text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(tbuffer,&start_iter,&end_iter,FALSE);
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(path, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s", text);
    fclose(fp);
```